# How can I set the locale for a script run by Postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix

I have a pipe alias in postfix to pass off emails to a simple executable:

```
test: "|/home/postfix_user/test/test-exe"
```

All this executable does is write a file with a UTF8 name to the disk. I can run it by hand just fine:

```
$ cd /home/postfix_user/test ; ./test-exe ; ls 
ACCIÓN.txt
```

However, when I execute the script through Postfix, I get an error message:

> Remote Server returned '< #5.3.0 x-unix; test-exe: /home/postfix_user/test/ACCIN.txt: openFile: invalid argument (invalid character)>'

The specifics of that error message (coming from a Haskell program) tell me that my locale is probably not set correctly to be UTF8. Orginally, I thought this was because of the shell that Postfix invokes the executable with, but setting the local command shell to be `sh` didn't seem to help. I've read through most of the postfix documentation (http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html, http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html, http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html, etc), but can't find anyway to do this.

The output of `locale` for `postfix_user` does state that it's UTF8:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 2):

Postfix by default will export certain environment variables, which can be found by running `postconf -d | grep export_environment` (postconf -d is a dump of all of the configurations for your postfix instance, not just the ones you manually set in `main.cf`)

At least on my system, the default instance was:

```
export_environment = TZ MAIL_CONFIG LANG
```

I'm not sure where that `LANG` variable is being set, but Postfix was pulling in `LANG=C` from somewhere. To override this, and set your own locale. Modify that conf value in `main.cf` to specify what locale you want to use:

```
export_environment = TZ MAIL_CONFIG LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:
Postfix will read `/etc/default/postfix` if it exists (at least on Debian).

Since forwarding `LANG` is already part of `export_environment`'s default you may  add

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to `/etc/default/postfix` (or maybe source `/etc/default/locale` there) instead of altering `export_environment`.